# My settings activity (using shared preferences) is not saving data, it is showing default values only

Tags: java, android

I am currently working on an android app, for which I created a settings activity. I used shared preferences, but it isn't working as it is supposed to. I open the settings page, toggle the switches, remove the app from memory, but when I open it again, the default settings are shown. I have no idea why. Please help. Also, I am a beginner, since I have started coding quite recently, so forgive me if I made a silly mistake.

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String SETTINGS_PREFERENCES = "com.example.taskmasterv3.SettingsPreferences";
    Switch switchReminder, switchNotifications;
    boolean reminders;
    boolean notifications;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        switchReminder = findViewById(R.id.switchReminder);
        switchNotifications = findViewById(R.id.switchNotifications);

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
         boolean reminder = prefs.getBoolean("reminders",true );
         boolean notification = prefs.getBoolean("notifications", false);

        switchReminder.setChecked(reminder);
        switchNotifications.setChecked(notification);





        if (switchReminder.isChecked())
        {
            reminders = true;
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putBoolean("reminders", reminders);
            editor.apply();
        }



        if (switchNotifications.isChecked())
        {
            notifications = true;
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putBoolean("notifications", notifications);
            editor.apply();

        }






    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean that you "remove the app from memory"?

Comment: I mean, I click on the recent apps button, and then remove it from there. Like I run the app, adjust the settings, and then restart the app. But the settings then again come back to their default state.

Answer (score 0):

I have get where you are getting error. You are actually unable to set that data.

```
if (switchReminder.isChecked())
    {
        reminders = true;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putBoolean("reminders", reminders);
        editor.apply();
    }



    if (switchNotifications.isChecked())
    {
        notifications = true;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putBoolean("notifications", notifications);
        editor.apply();

    }
```

It directly called when you start the activity. But, this function doesn't called on changing state of switch.

So, you have to add a listener like following source code.

```
switchReminder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     //enter your code here
if (switchReminder.isChecked())
{
    reminders = true;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putBoolean("reminders", reminders);
    editor.apply();
}

})
```

Add `setOnClickListener()` on `switchNotifications` also. Than, I hope it will work.

edited :

```
//setOnClickListener 
switchReminder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
if (switchReminder.isChecked())
{
    reminders = true;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putBoolean("reminders", reminders);
    editor.apply();
}

})
```

That was for only `switchRemider`. and, following source code is for `switchNotification`.

```
//setOnClickListener 
switchNotifications.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
if (switchNotifications.isChecked())
    {
        notifications = true;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putBoolean("notifications", notifications);
        editor.apply();

    }

})
```

You have add both code instead of

```
if (switchReminder.isChecked())
    {
        reminders = true;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putBoolean("reminders", reminders);
        editor.apply();
    }



    if (switchNotifications.isChecked())
    {
        notifications = true;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putBoolean("notifications", notifications);
        editor.apply();

    }
```

Comment: I am confused, the place where you have marked ' place your code here', what more code do I have to paste there? I just did it exactly as you did...

Comment: @Aadhitya Check it I have edited my answer.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for your help, but I fixed it. I'll just post my answer.

Comment: @Aadhitya Happy to know. You fixed your own problem.

Comment: @Aadhitya Sorry! I couldn't get you.

Comment: Just saying that sometimes we answer our own problems...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I finally got this to work. i just added a save button to save my settings. Now it works like a charm. Here is the code :

```
public static final String SETTINGS_PREFERENCES = "com.example.taskmasterv3.SettingsPreferences";
    SwitchCompat switchReminder, switchNotifications;
    Button btnSaveSettings;
    boolean remind;
    boolean notify;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        switchReminder = findViewById(R.id.switchReminder);
        switchNotifications = findViewById(R.id.switchNotifications);
        btnSaveSettings = findViewById(R.id.btnSaveSettings);

        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean reminder = preferences.getBoolean("remind", true);
        boolean notification = preferences.getBoolean("notify", false);

        if (reminder)
        {
            switchReminder.setChecked(true);
        }
        if (notification)
        {
            switchNotifications.setChecked(true);
        }


        btnSaveSettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                finish();

                if (switchReminder.isChecked())
                {
                    remind = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    remind = false;
                }
                if (switchNotifications.isChecked())
                {
                    notify = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    notify = false;
                }
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putBoolean("remind", remind);
                editor.putBoolean("notify", notify);
                editor.commit();
            }
        });
























    }

}
```